# Gradio Dropdown Option Hints/Tips text on hover how to do this?

Tags: python, dropdown, gradio

When as user hovers over an option how do you have the hovered over option display a hint of text describing what the option means/does/etc...?

I'm using gradio
calling the following:

```
`steps_defaults_options=["step1","step2"]

STEPS_defaults_dropdown = gr.Dropdown(steps_defaults_options, label="Steps", info="Steps GPT Engineer will take")`
```